# Designing a library for Hardware-accelerated unsupported containers on iOS (and Airplay)

Tags: ios, gstreamer, h.264, airplay

I'm trying to put together an open source library that allows iOS devices to play files with unsupported containers, as long as the track formats/codecs are supported. e.g.: a Matroska video (MKV) file with an H264 video track and an AAC audio track. I'm making an app that surely could use that functionality and I bet there are many more out there that would benefit from it. Any help you can give (by commenting here or—even better— collaborating with me) is much appreciated. This is where I'm at so far:

I did a bit of research trying to find out how players like AVPlayerHD or Infuse can play non-standard containers and still have hardware acceleration. It seems like they transcode small chunks of the whole video file and play those in sequence instead.

It's a good solution. But if you want to throw that video to an Apple TV, things don't work as planned since the video is actually a bunch of smaller chunks being played as a playlist. [This site](http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html) has way more info, but at its core streaming to Apple TV is essentially a progressive download of the MP4/MPV file being played.

I'm thinking a sort of streaming proxy is the way to go. For the playing side of things, I've been investigating AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#513)) as a way of playing the video track. I haven't gotten to audio yet. Things get interesting when you think about the AirPlay side of things: by having a "container proxy", we can make any file look like it has the right container without the file size implications of transcoding.

It seems like GStreamer might be a good starting point for the proxy. I need to read up on it; I've never used it before. Does this approach sound like a good one for a library that could be used for App Store apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got some extra time to go over GStreamer. Especially [this article about how it is already updated to use the hardware decoding provided by iOS 8](https://coaxion.net/blog/2014/09/gstreamer-with-hardware-video-codecs-on-ios/). So no need to develop this; GStreamer seems to be the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 'chucked' solution is no longer necessary in iOS 8. You should simply set up a video decode session and pass in NALUs.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#513

Comment: Yes, I have linked it in the third paragraph of my original post. But that doesn't solve the AirPlay side of things. It looks like GStreamer is the way to go.